# Can we test out a bunch of different ColorRamps with the Asset Browser?

Tags: shaders

[image]

I've set up a basic color ramp here which just has a bunch of different colors in it.

I want to be able to prototype different color ramps by swapping them in and out - perhaps with the asset browser.

I was wondering pretty much 2 things:

1. What is the quickest way to drag in and prototype different variations of ColorRamp and
2. If there is a downloadable library of ColorRamps which I can draw from so I don't have to create my own. Heres photoshop's gradient library for reference:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that you can have a single node as an asset. Maybe place them in a material or node group (probably no preview available for node groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just <s>Frankensteined</s> *cough* created a script from other questions (like this one here [How to set Hex in RGB Node? (Python)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/158896/107598)) to import color ramp definitions. Done this, I've found this question: [Efficient method for putting colormaps into color ramp?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/261360/107598) which already offers scripts for this purpose. <sup>(**pah! "thank you", search! A little bit late for this finding, heh?*)</sup>

Anyway, you can find color ramp/palette/gradient definitions online ([Esri Color Ramps](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/visualization/symbols-color-ramps/esri-color-ramps/#ramps) and [hex color-palette](https://www.color-hex.com/color-palette/36366)) and then use one of the scripts to create a material with it. The definitions come in different formats like the hex format (*#FF0080*) or decimal format (*RGB(255, 0, 128)*).

I didn't find a way to properly set the *mapping* node values to see all the colors of the color ramp in the material preview, so I adjusted them manually. Maybe anyone else knows... Hope this helps and gives you an idea.

[image: screenshot]